# Get Columns Range from column number variable [VBA]

Tags: vba

I have a variable called 'columnIndex' and i want to copy **five** columns from this variable.

I could use something like the code bellow to copy two columns.

```
columnIndex = 10
Range(Columns(columnIndex),Columns(columnIndex+1)).Copy
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Columns(columnIndex).Resize(,5).Copy
```

Comment: i was waiting something like this. Thanks!